# get results of two different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have to mysql tables (tableA, tableB)

**tableA**

```
ID | username
1  | Max Power
```

**tableB**

```
ID | book      | userID 
9  | MyBook    | 1
```

Now I would like all the results of tableB with php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","database","username","password");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tableB`";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();      
$result = $statement->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
   echo $row->book; //MyBook
   echo $row->userID, //1
}
```

But instead of userID = 1, I would like to know, how is userID 1?
I would like to get the result "Max Power"
How I have to modify the sql query to get this information ?

Comment: You need a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: You need to JOIN two tables.

Comment: thanks a lot !! :)